# Changing text / image on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

Heyo ! 
Im working with some CSS and am having trouble getting things to change on hover.

```
.wclan{
    background: url(icon url here);
    width: 23%;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 25.5%;
    z-index: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 7px;
}

.wclan:hover{ 
    background: #d710ca;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 3000;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 7px;
}
```

Im looking for the image to change on hover. Showing a preview 'icon' if you will and when you hover it'll change to show information. The problem is how timely it is to find a image size that works with all sizes (since my code is using percentages it can be different for every computer) as well as having it change. I was thinking of working my way around this problem with background URL, but I feel as if it could be easier if I just used a PNG in the HTML..I just don't know how to get the PNG to change on hover like the rest of the code.

Hopefully that made sense. Thanks !

Comment: I'm confused. Are you having the initial state be an image and then on hover show a different image? Initial state be an image, on hover change to a background color? Or do you want an image AND a background color, and do something with that on hover?

Comment: `z-index: absolute;` is invalid, you have a lot of values duplicated needlessly between your hovered and non-hovered versions... Question, what type of element is `.wclan` being applied to? Also really confused as to what your actual problem is haha

Comment: @jlane09 Hey !! sorry about that. Yeah, I want the original 'image' to be replaced with another image on hover. I forgot to remove the color to make it more clear aaa !! The issue is that since the code is a indefinite number (since it can change with any computer screen at 100%) so its hard to find a image that can satisfy every computer screen. Is there any easier way? (if that didn't make any sense I'm so sorry I'm bad with words)

Comment: @abluejelly Sorry aa !!! .wclan is being applied to a HTML div element if that makes any sense ! sorry I'm self taught so i probably don't make much sense //mm\\  <div="wclan"></div>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine . If you want to change the image on hover just specify a different background image path on hover . Look below :

```
.wclan{ background-image: url(icon url 1); }

/*Change image url on hover*/

.wclan:hover{ background-image: url(icon url 2 ); }
```

Comment: Thank you !! I see whatcha mean

Answer (score 0):

I added some margin code and deleted the % reference. If a value is '0', you do not need to follow it with a suffix like 'px' or'%'. This may work just fine with position:relative;, because the margin 'auto' keeps it bound to the center of the screen.

```
 body, .wclan {background: url(icon url here); width: 23%; height: 150px; position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;margin:0 auto; z-index:-1; text-align: center; border-radius: 0px; font-size: 7px;
 }

.wclan:hover {background-color: #d710ca; width: 100%; height: 150px; position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 3000; text-align: center; border-radius: 0px; font-size: 7px;
 }
```

Comment: The margin:0 auto; is used when you need your main page (not the BG screen/body) to always stay in the center of the browser screen, no matter how wide you make it. The '0' means no top or bottom margin (not for the main div). 'Auto' left and right tells the browser to always keep the main page in the center of the screen. Normally all other div's are inside this main div, including popup messages, etc. All of these objects will scroll vertically in sync. This does not affect any tool-bars attached to the top or side of the browser.

Comment: Margin is simply the spacing around your page / division. It can be defined by pixels or %.